Grab tool attaching to the plane in the Z direction
I'm a beginner and I'm not sure why when i use g+z/move tool, it causes it to not move in the z direction only. It like snaps to the ground, idk why.

Example:

Uncheck the 'project individual elements'. You either have the Snap tool active or you are pressing ctrl while moving it. Tbh I don't know why it behaves like that but it seems to stop when you uncheck it

I think having the snap active while it's constrained to n axis makes it behave as if the pivot point was set to View. Simmmilar to how pressing G twice makes it behaves as if it was in Local. Either way you should uncheck it cuz it's not needed even if you want to use the snap tool

Thanks, I was stupid and didn't turn off snapping. Apologies for asking this.
